# Need the latest entry in a specific column for Fivem Lua/MySQL

Tags: mysql, lua

So basically im trying to make it where the citizenID in a qbcore server is numerical only (this bit was easy as) but issue is, I cannot figure out how to grab the latest entry into the citizenID column in my DB, so that i can increment it by 1. So say my ID is 1, the next character someone makes should be 2 and so forth.

```
function QBCore.Player.CreateCitizenId()
    local UniqueFound = false
    local CitizenId = nil
    while not UniqueFound do
        local lastID = MySQL.prepare.await('SELECT MAX(citizenid) FROM players')
        local lastIDStr = tostring(lastID)
        local lastIDInt = tonumber(lastIDStr)
        if lastIDInt == 0 then
            CitizenId = 1
        elseif lastIDInt >= '1' then
            CitizenId = lastID + 1
        end
        local result = MySQL.prepare.await('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM players WHERE citizenid = ?', { CitizenId })
        if result == 0 then
            UniqueFound = true
        end
    end
    return CitizenId
end
```

Honestly it is a mess of code. Right now the error I get in my terminal is (attempting to index a string with nil (the string being the '1' in the elseif line, and the nil being the lastIDInt

I need the SQL query to be in the one line too. Im still learning all this stuff so i apologise if the answer is simple but it eludes me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely what your problem is here, but I can see an issue right off the bat.
Firstly, on your elseif line you are trying to compare a number, `lastIDInt`, with a string `'1'` . This just will not work so you should compare it with a number: `lastIDInt >= 1`

I cannot see anywhere in your code that would cause the error you are describing however, but the above may fix your problem.

Comment: I tried it originally like how you had it. And then I got “attempted to compare a number (being the 1 as an integer) with nil (meaning lastIDInt can’t be found). Apparently my SQL query doesn’t work

Comment: Yep that looks like the issue.